# How to read this state in quantum physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, notation

I am having a little trouble understanding this state: 
$$
\,^3D\left[3/2\right]_{1/2}
$$

What does the $[3/2]$ indicate here?

Comment: Could you perhaps provide some context?

Comment: This is not a standard notation across fields. Give context.

Comment: It is in the paper on the quantum computation, the state diagram of the Yb ion.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Deexcitation times for ytterbium](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/212502/deexcitation-times-for-ytterbium)

Comment: With due apologies to a long-vanished OP, I re-asked this question in a fuller form, with an answer, at [What do term symbols like $^3[3/2]_{1/2}$, with a half-integer "$L$", mean?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/229564/what-do-term-symbols-like-33-2-1-2-with-a-half-integer-l-mean)