# Is angular momentum only in orbital or spin?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

While I am learning Quantum Mechanics with [angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum) and the two types of them:

- orbital angular momentum
- and internal angular momentum a.k.a. spin
- (and total angular momentum, but that is a combined version).

So,

> Is there any other types of angular momentum that does not recorded in textbooks or common literature?

*PS. I am just talking about angular momentum in general Physics*

Comment: Vorticity.  Quantum vortices are observed in nuclear physics and in superconductors.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero How is that different from orbital angular momentum?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I'm not too sure what the question means so my comment may not be applicable, but basically it's applicable to non-rigid bodies so it's neither intrinsic spin nor orbital angular momentum. Think of a bucket rotating about its axis: the water in it doesn't need to rotate at the same angular velocity as the bucket.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero The vorticity in a superconductor boils down to a phase gradient of the wavefunction of a quantum particle which has a nonzero integral around a line of phase singularity. As such, it fits perfectly as an orbital angular momentum - it's no different than the angular momentum of an electron in a hydrogen atom. In a bucket, each particle has a different angular momentum but each particle still has *orbital* angular momentum.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty    Yeah fair enough.  I'm not "attached" to vorticity: I just remember this being treated separately from the other two in nuclear physics.  Classically you are certainly right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. All angular momenta are either orbital, spin, or a linear combination of the two.

The worst you end up getting is wonky mixtures like [these ones](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/229564/what-do-term-symbols-with-a-half-integer-l-like-33-2-1-2-mean), where you mix the spin orbital angular momenta of different shells inside an atom in some weird order, or [funky linear combinations of the two](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256386/photons-with-half-integer-angular-momentum-whats-happening) (and while we're at this, [the photon spin has some tricky behaviour](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46643/why-is-the-s-z-0-state-forbidden-for-photons)), but they all boil down to those two components.

More generally, there is a meaningful distinction between *intrinsic* angular momenta $\mathbf L_\mathrm{i}$, which do not change when you displace the origin, and *extrinsic* angular momenta $\mathbf L_\mathrm{e}$, which transform as
$$
\mathbf L_\mathrm e\mapsto \mathbf L_\mathrm e'=\mathbf L_e-\mathbf r_0\times\mathbf P
$$
when you displace the system as $\mathbf r\mapsto \mathbf r'=\mathbf r-\mathbf r_0$, and where $\mathbf P$ is the total angular momentum of the system. As regards your question, though, they are just descriptors that apply respectively to spin and orbital angular momenta.

Comment: I felt a bit risky since the question I am asking is not something I can prove at my level. However, I trust what you say so here is the tick =)